# Echo out the data from RESTful API using Laravel

Tags: json, ajax, rest, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

This piece of code connects to the API perfectly, I want to echo out the data on this API on a blade form, how do I do this?

```
        public function create()
        {
            $guzzle = new Client([
                'base_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8800/dialects/',
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'type' => 'GET',
                    'crossDomain' => true,
                    'dataType' => 'jsonp'
                ]
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: Your question is very vague.

Comment: How, please? So as to furnish where it's lacking.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what exactly "echoing out the data on this API on a blade form" mean. Please provide more context. Do you want to use the data of the HTTP request (made by guzzle) and use it in a blade form?

Comment: You're correct. Perfect!!! I want to use the data from the API in a blade form.

Comment: Great.  You should simply render a view and pass the data to it. Do you have any specific problem?

Comment: I've done that just now but not seeing anything. Hope I'm doing it the right way?  the code: ```return view('pages.songs.index')->with('guzzle', $guzzle);``` and on the page: ```@if(!count($guzzle) > 0)
 <p> test </p>
@else
 @foreach($guzzle as $guz)
  <p>$guz</p>
 @endforeach
@endif```

Comment: Well, you are just creating a guzzle client. You haven't sent the request yet, Based on the guzzle docs you should call the `request` method for sending a HTTP request. `$response = $guzzle->request(...);` http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#creating-a-client

Comment: I have just made the request, still not displaying data: ```$response = $client->request('GET', 'dialects');```

Comment: The `dialects` resource exist in your client base route. I think what you want is just `/`. You can use `var_dump` for checking the response.

Comment: This question needed/needs an [mcve] in order to remain open (there is plenty of code in the comments that needs to be in the question itself). Putting on hold for now.